# How to fix SharePoint Online sidebar navigation?

Tags: sharepoint, menu, sharepoint-online

I am looking an issue in SharePoint Online site. Here menus are not getting collapses while I am clicking on other 1-Level menus. enter image description here
[image]
In the above image first I click on the Pages menu to see the submenus inside this. After that I clicked on the Inspections menu to see its sub-menus, on the same time Pages sub-menus hierarchy is not get collapsed. Can anyone please advise what is the way here how menus will get open/ close hierarchy? Currently this is menus are getting collapse if I am clinking on the upward caret icon.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, it's by default that after you have expanded an expanded menu, this expanded menus will always be expanded and displayed, you have to manually collapse this expanded menus.